# GPX Logger iOS 7

Tags: ios, gps, ios7, location

I have question is there any library or tutorial for iOS 7, how to create simple GPS logging application. I need output in **GPX file**. This file will be processed with PHP api and after that rendered to MapBox map.

I tried to use google but i don't find any relevant searches.

Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Do you have problems with gathering location data or generating GPX file. Or both?

Comment: I have problem with gathering location data, i don't find any information how to do it.

Comment: [Here is a downloadable example](http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/06/04/how-to-add-gps-to-your-ios-app-part-1/). You would probably want to crate a `NSMutableArray` of `CLLocation` objects - you'd be adding them to the array in `didUpdateToLocation:`. Then - probably when stop is tapped - this location data can be transformed to [GPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) and uploaded on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Read the LocationAwareness Guide from Apple: Then you should now how to get GPS coordinates.

The file format for GPX files should be easily found with a bit of googling.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "What’s New in Core Location" video [here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/).